# My php code works on localhost, but doesn't work on the actual server

Tags: php, mysql

This is probably a pretty basic question...but
I'm trying to create a basic php survey in Eclipse with xampp that inputs data into a database. It works just fine on the localhost, but whenever I upload it to the website using Filezilla, it just displays the PHP text.

What I tried then to do is create the database and the table on the actual website (the code of which works perfectly on localhost), but I get a "The page cannot be found" error (the website is www.digitalcowboyrepair.com and the link I entered was www.digitalcowboyrepair/createdatabase.php" Here's the code

Createdatabase.php

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    // Create database
    $sql="CREATE DATABASE testdb1";
    if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        echo "Database testdb1 created successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($con);
    }

?>
```

Comment: you cannot access `Createdatabase.php` using `www.digitalcowboyrepair/createdatabase.php` URL it must be `www.digitalcowboyrepair/Createdatabase.php`. remember *nix is case sensitive

Comment: Is php installed on the server. Try firing `phpinfo();` command. Let me know what the output is

Comment: You should put those ini_set settings into your php.ini, or at least in a .htaccess via php_value directives. If whatever's causing this problem occurs early enough in the startup sequence, PHP may never actually GET to the ini_set() calls in the first place.

Comment: Just FYI for the future since you said you were unable to format your code properly here, to format code blocks they need to have two returns from the previous line and they need to be indented 4 spaces. You can do this by highlighting the code and clicking the code button ( `{ }` ) above the text area.

Comment: @bansi actually the server is Windows.

Comment: @user2584492 As an aside, even though this is `localhost`, you should *never* post code that contains credentials.

Comment: I apologize, let me make myself more accurate. The file is createdatabase.php and thats what I put in, I capitalized it in my post by accident, and where is php.ini? And thank you smerny

Comment: Thanks Sam, I wasnt even thinking about that

Answer (score 1):

Your production server is `Server:Microsoft-IIS/6.0`

The instructions for installing PHP on IIS 6 are at http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis6.php

Here are the headers from the Server response:

```
HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified
Content-Location: http://www.digitalcowboyrepair.com/index.html
Last-Modified: Mon, 15 Jul 2013 17:15:42 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 5.0_Pub
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 15 Jul 2013 17:57:35 GMT
```

If you do not already have `MySQL` installed on the server, you can find the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-installation.html

Comment: So I install this then just run the website again?

Comment: you will need to install mysql too, but yes, after installing PHP your php code should run

Answer (score 0):

Are you copying the file to the right server path? That may be the cause of the "Page not found" error. In IIS the default folder is "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\", if not maybe your server has a virtual directory pointing to another filesystem path.

Then you'll be able to execute the file. If the server shows PHP source code instead echo messages you'll have to install PHP module for IIS and install the mysql libraries for PHP.